# RelativeSource self binding working on control but not when inside style setter

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

This is for Windows Phone 8.

Let's say I have a set of `TextBlocks` that I want to change their foreground color on depending on the text they're bound to.

```
if (text == "0")
  return Red;
else
  return Green;
```

I can achieve this using a relative source binding:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource TextBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
```

But if I move this to a style setter, it no longer works as expected:

```
<Style x:Name="MyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                Value="{Binding Text, 
                    Converter={StaticResource TextBrushConverter}, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
```

Why doesn't this way work? It'd be nice to reuse this style (in reality, a set of these).

Comment: Did you try `TemplatedParent` instead of `Self`?